# Sending email in PHP

Tags: php, email, pear

I'm trying to send email using PHP. I found many posts here and I feel lost. I tried to use many codes but none of them works.

Finally, I read about PEAR and I have the following code, I'm working on Mac OSX 10.7.3 with MAMP having PHP 5.3.6.

What do I need to do to have the code works, it shows an error loading page!? Is there any configurations?

If anyone has a working example with instructions for configurations, please share.

```
<?php
require_once "Mail.php";

$recipients = 'receiver@live.com';

$headers['From']    = 'sender@gmail.com';
$headers['To']      = 'receiver@live.com';
$headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';

$body = 'Test message';

$params['sendmail_path'] = '/usr/lib/sendmail';

// Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
$mail_object =& Mail::factory('sendmail', $params);

$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
  echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
 } else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PHP sending an email couldn't be simpler:

```
mail('to@email.com', 'Subject', 'Here comes the message');
```

That's it. Keep in mind that your server needs to be configured to send email though.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: What configurations do I need and where???

Comment: Honestly I've never had to do it (every server I've rented has always been configured properly), but reading [this guide](http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/Configure_PHP_to_Use_a_Local_Mail_Server_for_Sending_Mail.htm) it seems all you need to do is set the `sendmail_path` variable in php.ini to point to your sendmail function. Exactly the same as you're doing in your code now (setting it to /usr/lib/sendmail) (although the articles suggests /usr/bin/sendmail or /usr/sbin/sendmail).